# D3 animation morphing polygon shape per frame - chronological order

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a d3.js visualization - that showcases different stages of a polygon shape - so having it animate/morph changing shape and scale.

Where the user click's on the little rectangles they essentially scroll through an array of data of "dimensions/coordinates" that showcase a "frame" of a shape (like a film frame)

so imagine - we have these shapes in an array --- a way of morphing/animating one to the other -- or/and using the rectangles to click and switch to that shape.

[image]
[image]

So the data would be an array of shapes/positions

```
[
{"coordinateX": 20, "coordinateY": 30, "shape": [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
        {"x":8.5,"y":23.4}, {"x":13.0,"y":21.0}, {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}], "frame": 0, "date": 2023-05-23 10:00},
{"coordinateX": 19, "coordinateY": 29, "shape": [{"x":0.3, "y":23.0},
        {"x":8.5,"y":23.4}, {"x":33.0,"y":21.0}, {"x":19.0,"y":45.5}], "frame": 1, "date": 2023-05-24 11:00},
{"coordinateX": 19, "coordinateY": 30, "shape": [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
        {"x":5.5,"y":23.7}, {"x":11.0,"y":21.0}, {"x":12.0,"y":13.5}], "frame": 2, "date": 2023-05-25 11:00}
]
```

Dimensions and coordinates - scale and adjustment of shape per frame - chronological order

so morph the existing shape - into others..

here is some code samples to draw a static polygon

//example of drawing a polygon
[Proper format for drawing polygon data in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204562/proper-format-for-drawing-polygon-data-in-d3)
http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/

```
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
         .attr("width", 1000)
         .attr("height", 667),

scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-30,30])
        .range([0,600]),

scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,50])
        .range([500,0]),

poly = [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
        {"x":8.5,"y":23.4},
        {"x":13.0,"y":21.0},
        {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}];

vis.selectAll("polygon")
    .data([poly])
  .enter().append("polygon")
    .attr("points",function(d) { 
        return d.map(function(d) { return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(","); }).join(" ");})
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

---

with the data array -

http://jsfiddle.net/5k9z30vh/

I want to figure out a way of aniamting/morphing polygons.

how would I look at animating/morphing - through the polygons -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1zHa1sAno0
[Loop D3 animation of polygon vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818039/loop-d3-animation-of-polygon-vertex)

```
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
         .attr("width", 1000)
         .attr("height", 667),

scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-30,30])
        .range([0,600]),

scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,50])
        .range([500,0]),

poly = [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
        {"x":8.5,"y":23.4},
        {"x":13.0,"y":21.0},
        {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}];
        
        var data = [{
        "coordinateX": 20,
        "coordinateY": 30,
        "shape": [{
                "x": 0.0,
                "y": 25.0
            },
            {
                "x": 8.5,
                "y": 23.4
            }, {
                "x": 13.0,
                "y": 21.0
            }, {
                "x": 19.0,
                "y": 15.5
            }
        ],
        "frame": 0,
        "date": "2023-05-23 10:00"
    },
    {
        "coordinateX": 19,
        "coordinateY": 29,
        "shape": [{
                "x": 0.3,
                "y": 23.0
            },
            {
                "x": 8.5,
                "y": 23.4
            }, {
                "x": 33.0,
                "y": 21.0
            }, {
                "x": 19.0,
                "y": 45.5
            }
        ],
        "frame": 1,
        "date": "2023-05-24 10:00"
    },
    {
        "coordinateX": 19,
        "coordinateY": 30,
        "shape": [{
                "x": 0.0,
                "y": 25.0
            },
            {
                "x": 5.5,
                "y": 23.7
            }, {
                "x": 11.0,
                "y": 21.0
            }, {
                "x": 12.0,
                "y": 13.5
            }
        ],
        "frame": 2,
        "date": "2023-05-25 10:00"
    }
]
        

vis.selectAll("polygon")
    .data([data[0].shape])
  .enter().append("polygon")
    .attr("points",function(d) { 
        return d.map(function(d) { return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(","); }).join(" ");})
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

hand drawing a polygon
https://jsfiddle.net/7pwaLfth/

https://lucidar.me/en/d3.js/part-06-basic-shapes/
https://gist.github.com/RiseupDev/b07f7ccc1c499efc24e9

### 30th May 2023 update

I have managed to create this demo that shows the concept working - the polygon morphs into the next -- this would be useful to showcase a "wound" healing from day 1 to day x -- essentially it would shrink into eventual non-existence..

I would like to fix/add these features/issues

-- there is a bug if you click on autoplay too much like event bubbling - if there is a way to avoid a malfunction if the user clicks too quickly

- I'd like to add different speeds/fps options -- be able to watch a frame each second 1fps, or 2 frames a second 2fp ---- to try and make it more fluent watching a wound heal in timelapse almost
  --- fix the overall structure of the visualization -- create a sketlon - g placeholders -- fix the ability to scale the visualization cleanly
- the polygon holder has no transformation to really align things properly
  -- the polygons are really big - I dont know how to just make them smaller - and if I reduce the canvas size then polygons become clipped --I dont know how to clean up the attachment of the little rectangle bar controller - it just seemed created/appended in a clunky manner

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5kqLftzy/

```js
let polygons = [{
    id: "1",
    plot: "469,59.5625,246,256.5625,348,499.5625,527,482.5625,653,457.5625,693,406.5625,732,371.5625,743,260.5625,690,257.5625,650,172.5625,622,143.5625,589,98.5625,544,90.5625,511,55.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    plot: "462,79.5625,258,258.5625,361,470.5625,527,482.5625,653,457.5625,693,406.5625,718,363.5625,705,284.5625,684,241.5625,650,172.5625,622,143.5625,587,108.5625,544,90.5625,513,95.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    plot: "410,173.5625,324,259.5625,361,470.5625,527,435.5625,604,379.5625,672,374.5625,718,363.5625,692,281.5625,662,231.5625,650,172.5625,622,143.5625,582,132.5625,544,90.5625,513,95.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    plot: "422,186.5625,359,267.5625,374,430.5625,527,435.5625,604,379.5625,672,374.5625,691,325.5625,692,281.5625,662,231.5625,650,172.5625,622,143.5625,582,132.5625,543,111.5625,503,124.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    plot: "486,200.5625,359,267.5625,394,393.5625,527,435.5625,604,379.5625,617,332.5625,634,292.5625,624,252.5625,602,216.5625,606,192.5625,596,171.5625,585,148.5625,573,175.5625,525,175.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    plot: "486,200.5625,440,264.5625,419,370.5625,527,435.5625,604,379.5625,580,359.5625,589,330.5625,607,306.5625,610,277.5625,604,252.5625,588,246.5625,577,238.5625,549,220.5625,514,219.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    plot: "485,272.5625,469,294.5625,456,359.5625,491,396.5625,604,379.5625,580,359.5625,589,330.5625,607,306.5625,610,277.5625,604,252.5625,588,246.5625,571,265.5625,548,270.5625,521,277.5625"
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    plot: "499,297.5625,483,310.5625,488,333.5625,492,356.5625,534,366.5625,566,349.5625,589,330.5625,607,306.5625,610,277.5625,593,273.5625,578,275.5625,571,265.5625,548,270.5625,521,277.5625"
  }
];

let width = 1000;
let height = 600;

let polyMaxY = 300;

var vis = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height),
  scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([-30, 30]).range([0, 600]),
  scaleY = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range([polyMaxY, 0]);

let polyStage = vis
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "polyStage")
  .attr("transform", "0 0");

let thePolygon = polyStage
  .append("polygon")
  .attr("id", "mainPoly")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("points", polygons[0]);

let paddingBottom = 50;

let chooserX = 100;
let chooserY = polyMaxY + paddingBottom;

let buttonWidth = 7;
let buttonHeight = 50;
let buttonRightPadding = 3;

let selectedColor = "aqua";
let rectColor = "black";

let currentPoly = 0;

let animationDuration = 2000;
let goRightDelay = 1000;
let autoplay = true;

let framePicker = vis.append("g").attr("class", "framePicker");

let buttonGroups = framePicker
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(polygons)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", buttonGroupTranslate);

buttonGroups
  .append("rect")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "chooserRect" + i)
  .attr("width", buttonWidth)
  .attr("height", buttonHeight)
  .style("fill", rectColor);

buttonGroups.on("click", navigateTo);

// Listen to left and right arrow
d3.select("body").on("keydown", function() {
  let keyCode = d3.event.keyCode;
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    //  37 is left arrow
    goLeft();
  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    goRight();
  }
});

function goLeft() {
  let nextIndex = currentPoly - 1;
  if (nextIndex < 0) {
    nextIndex = polygons.length - 1;
  }
  navigateTo("", nextIndex);
}

function goRight() {
  let nextIndex = currentPoly + 1;
  if (nextIndex >= polygons.length) {
    nextIndex = 0;
  }
  navigateTo("", nextIndex);
}

function buttonGroupTranslate(d, i) {
  let groupX = chooserX + i * (buttonWidth + buttonRightPadding);
  return "translate(" + groupX + "," + chooserY + ")";
}

function navigateTo(d, i) {
  buttonGroups.selectAll("rect").style("fill", rectColor); // reset all colors
  d3.select("#chooserRect" + i).style("fill", selectedColor); // set color for the current one
  d3.select("#mainPoly")
    .transition()
    .duration(animationDuration)
    .attr("points", polygons[i]["plot"]);
  currentPoly = i;
}

let timerCallBack = function() {
  return function() {
    if (autoplay) {
      goRight();
      d3.timer(timerCallBack(), animationDuration + goRightDelay); // Set up a new timer
    }
    return true; // Cancel the current timer
  };
};

function beginAutoPlay() {
  autoplay = true;
  d3.timer(timerCallBack(), animationDuration + goRightDelay);
}

function stopAutoPlay() {
  autoplay = false;
}

navigateTo("", currentPoly);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/d3js/3.5.9/d3.min.js"></script>
<h3>Draw a polygon 2</h3>
<div>
  <button onclick="beginAutoPlay()">Start Autoplay</button>
  <button onclick="stopAutoPlay()">Stop Autoplay</button>
</div>
```

1. there is a design for this - that is compact and simple - I have attached it again to showcase this -- its clearly small demo -- polygon shape no bigger than what - 200px by 200px - and rectangle controls directly under it.
2. there is in fact a bug - where you have event bubbling if you click too many times on those autoplay/autostop buttons - so thats a bug - that you should fix or have not happen anyway -- some functionality in place to ensure thats not a problem
3. add next to auto start/stop - 1fps, 2fps - also as buttons or such - so you can speed or slow the auto play anyhow - you already have the transition value as a variable - so making 2 buttons to control that - should be a piece of cake no?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand (too much information)... Can you just post examples of shapes before and after the morfing?

Comment: basically - I am asking - how can you morph/change the existing shape -- into other shapes given in the array -- so the array has slightly different shapes -- an animation - control to scroll into each

Comment: Pardon me for nagging: but I totally agree with Michael Rovinsky: Please, shorten your description. Actually, you can strip everthing before your 30th may update. The links in the first section are too generic and rather distracting. The autoply bug could probably be fixed with an additional condition like ` if(autoplay){d3.timer(timerCallBack(), animationDuration + 10)}`  . You might also adapt some aspects from this vanilla JS [example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/bGmXZJZ?editors=1000)

Comment: I dont see a difference in what those numbers do or what they represent? I felt maybe fps would be better